NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' error in Angular, importing modules does not fix the issue
I am trying to show a list of "Questions" on my Angular web page, they are hard-coded for now, I will fetch them from the back-end later on. ngFor is not recognized by the Angular project. I read some similar questions online and saw that I needed to import some modules (CommonModule and/or BrowserModule). I did that and I still get the error written in the title.
question.component.html:
  <button routerLink="/main-menu" class="logo">
    <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
  </button>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><button href="#" (click)="goToHome()">Main Menu</button></li>
      <li><button href="#" (click)="goToUser()">Profile</button></li>
      <li><button href="#" (click)="logout()">Logout</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

  <div *ngFor="let question of hardcodedQuestions" class="question-container">
    <div class="question-header">
      <div class="question-title">{{ question.title }}</div>
      <div class="question-author">Asked by {{ question.author }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="question-content">
      <p>{{ question.body }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question-meta">
      <span>Created on: {{ question.creationDate }} at {{ question.creationTime }}</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Answer Section -->
    <div class="answer-section">
      <textarea placeholder="Your answer..." rows="3" class="answer-input"></textarea>
      <div class="answer-meta">
        <span>Answered on: {{ currentDate }} at {{ currentTime }}</span>
      </div>
      <button (click)="submitAnswer()" class="submit-button">Submit Answer</button>
    </div>
  </div>

question.component.ts:
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Question } from './question.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  question1: Question | undefined;
  currentDate: string | undefined;
  currentTime: string | undefined;
  newAnswer: string | undefined;

  hardcodedQuestions: Question[] = [
    {
      title: 'Sample Question 1',
      author: 'John Doe',
      body: 'This is a sample question body 1.',
      creationDate: '2024-04-15',
      creationTime: '10:00 AM'
    },
    {
      title: 'Sample Question 2',
      author: 'Jane Smith',
      body: 'This is a sample question body 2.',
      creationDate: '2024-04-16',
      creationTime: '11:00 AM'
    },
    {
      title: 'Sample Question 3',
      author: 'Alice Johnson',
      body: 'This is a sample question body 3.',
      creationDate: '2024-04-17',
      creationTime: '12:00 PM'
    }
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.question1 = {
      title: 'Sample Question',
      author: 'John Doe',
      body: 'This is a sample question body.',
      creationDate: '2024-04-15',
      creationTime: '10:00 AM'
    };

    // Get current date and time
    const currentDateTime = new Date();
    this.currentDate = currentDateTime.toLocaleDateString();
    this.currentTime = currentDateTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
  }

  logout() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  goToUser() {
    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
  }

  goToHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['/question']);
  }

  submitAnswer() {
    const answer = this.newAnswer;
    console.log('Answer submitted:', answer);
    this.newAnswer = '';
  }
}

app.module.ts:
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app.routes";
import {UserComponent} from "../user/user.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "../login/login.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "../register/register.component";
import {QuestionComponent} from "../question/question.component";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ButtonModule} from "primeng/button";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    QuestionComponent
  ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ButtonModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [UserComponent]

})
export class AppModule {
}

